# Creation and validation of cluster for Bag of words

Tags: clustering, k-means, validation, hierarchical-clustering, bag-of-words

I recently came across a problem where I have been given a dataset of [Bag of words](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/bag-of-words/), the description of the dataset is given in the readme file.

What I have been trying to do is create clusters of docIDs who have highest matching wordIDs also considering the count/frequency of the words in a particular document if required.

What I tried doing is visualize the data in 3D space for the first 10 docIDs,

[image: 3d Graph]

but I could not understand how to create clusters from that? What I understand is, the documents having the maximum matching wordIDs will be/should be nearest to each other. But how do I do it?

I tried doing hierarchical clustering with the mean and standard deviation of the docIDs for the documents with this code:

```
cdata <- ddply(bagofwordsdata, c("docID"), summarise,mean = weighted.mean(wordID, count), sd=sd(rep(wordID,count)))
```

But after manual validation, what I could observe the farthest docIDs had more matching wordIDs than the nearest ones. Please guide me through this.